# Wordpress load-scripts.php not loading

Tags: javascript

Am currently using WordPress 4.6.1 with a custom theme created by me. Am using Theme My Login plugin for front-end user profile page. The scripts needed for generating passwords are not loading with my custom theme.

When I switch the theme to default theme the below script loads

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/priya/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=admin-bar,password-strength-meter,underscore,wp-util,user-profile,wp-embed&amp;ver=4.7.2'></script>
```

and generate password works.

But switching to my custom theme does not load the above script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer TrubinE, I already tried adding the scripts using wp_enqueue, but the feature is not working. The script has to be loaded in the below way. <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/priya/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=admin-bar,password-strength-meter,underscore,wp-util,user-profile,wp-embed&amp;ver=4.7.2'></script>

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * add script
 *
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
 */
function youplugin_add_frontend() {
    // js
    wp_enqueue_script('youplugin-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), 0.1, true);

}

// add script
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'youplugin_add_frontend');
```